# Interpretation of "enrollment date"

Tags: contract-law

I signed up for an exercise class on 7/18 ("this agreement entered into on") and the contract states it's in effect from 8/1 ("contract start date" and "contract in effect from").

The class has 30 day money back guarantee within "30 days of enrolling". Should the 30 day period be considered from date of signing the contract, or from the effective date of contract?

Comment: Why don't you just ask them?

Answer (score 1):

If the contract doesn't define it then "enrollment" would be given its normal English meaning - when the Studio accepted your application - so 7/18.